# PHP class not found when using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I am new with this namespace thing.

I have 2 classes(separate files) in my base directory, say `class1.php` and `class2.php` inside a directory `src/`.

**class1.php**

```
namespace \src\utility\Timer;

class Timer{
    public static function somefunction(){

    }
}
```

**class2.php**

```
namespace \src\utility\Verification;
use Timer;

class Verification{
     Timer::somefunction();
}
```

When I execute `class2.php`, i get the Fatal error that

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Timer' not found in path/to/class2.php at
>   line ***

I read somewhere on SO, that I need to create Autoloaders for this. If so, how do I approach into creating one, and if not, then what else is the issue?

**UPDATE**

I created an Autoloader which will `require` all the required files on top of my php script.
So, now the class2.php would end up like this.

```
namespace \src\utility\Verification;
require '/path/to/class1.php'
use Timer;
//or use src\utility\Timer ... both doesn't work.

class Verification{
     Timer::somefunction();
}
```

This also does not work, and it shows that class not found. But, if I remove all the `namespaces`, and `use`'s. Everything works fine.

Comment: Try in ur class2.php with use \src\Timer\Timer as Timer;

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh Tried. Same issue.

Comment: I think you should check out [Composer](http://getcomposer.org).  A namespace is merely a unique identifier for a class.  PHP's autoload is overloaded when a class is instantiated whilst it does not exist but before the pre-processor throws a T_FATAL error.  Common practice is to then replace `\ ` with `/` and load it from a folder structure (why the namespace usually matches a directory structure.

Comment: @ash Can you tell me in brief how Composer will be helpful in my project? I need to use Namespaces. I hope you have read my Update in the question.

Comment: It doesn't fix your namespaces, it helps you load your classes when to instansiate them in your code.  checkout [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Answer (score 28):

We can solve the namespace problem in two ways

[*1) We can just use namespace and require*](http://photonkhan.weebly.com/technical--review/using-namespace-in-php-without-using-the-composer#comments)

[*2) We can use Composer and work with the autoloading!*](http://photonkhan.weebly.com/technical--review/using-namespace-in-php-composer-method#comments)

**The First Way (Namespace and require) way**

> Class1.php (Timer Class)

```
namespace Utility;

class Timer
   {
    public static function {}
   }
```

> Class2.php (Verification Class)

```
namespace Utility;
require "Class1.php";

//Some interesting points to note down!
//We are not using the keyword "use" 
//We need to use the same namespace which is "Utility" 
//Therefore, both Class1.php and Class2.php has "namespace Utility"

//Require is usually the file path!
//We do not mention the class name in the require " ";
//What if the Class1.php file is in another folder?
//Ex:"src/utility/Stopwatch/Class1.php"  

//Then the require will be "Stopwatch/Class1.php"
//Your namespace would be still "namespace Utility;" for Class1.php

class Verification
   {
     Timer::somefunction();
   }
```

**The Second Way (Using Composer and the autoloading way)**

> Make **composer.json** file. According to your example "src/Utility"
>   We need to create a composer.json file before the src folder. Example: In a folder called myApp you will have composer.json file and a src folder.

```
   {
     "autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
        "Utility\\":"src/utility/"
        }
     }   
   }
```

Now go to that folder open your terminal in the folder location where there is composer.json file. Now type in the terminal!

```
   composer dump-autoload
```

This will create a vendor folder. Therefore if you have a folder named "MyApp"
you will see vendor folder, src folder and a composer.json file

> Timer.php(Timer Class)

```
namespace Utility;

class Timer
     {
      public static function somefunction(){}
     }
```

> Verification.php (Verification Class)

```
namespace Utility; 
require "../../vendor/autoload.php"; 
use Utility\Timer; 

class Verification
  {
     Timer::somefunction(); 
  }
```

This method is more powerful when you have a complex folder structure!!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to implement an autoloader, as you have already read about it in SO.

You could check the autoloading standard PSR-4 at http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ and you can see a sample implementation of PSR-4 autoloading and an example class implementation to handle multiple namespaces here https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md.

Comment: I see. I was in fact reading those right now. This means, that the keywords `namespace` and `use` are kinda useless without an Autoloader?

Comment: Namespaces are just a way of encapsulating items as the docs say